# List of files from box.com

Tags: box-api

I am trying to sync files uploaded in Box with another external system. Which API(s) do I use to get a "list of all files uploaded/updated after given dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss"?

cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I think the [User Events API](http://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-for-a-user) is going to be your best option.  This API will return to you the stream of events for a given user.  You will then need filter that stream down a bit per your requirements.  Some things to consider:

- This API doesn't return to you a list of events relative to a specified timestamp.  Instead, each event has a `created_at` field that you can use to filter down the result set to a particular point in time.
- The API doesn't feature super fine-grained event type filtering, ala 'only show me file create/update events.'  Instead, each event has an `event_type` field that indicates the nature of the event and can be used for filtering the results.  The event types that might interest you are:

  - ITEM_CREATE (File or folder created)
  - ITEM_UPLOAD (File or folder was uploaded [modified])
  - ITEM_MOVE (File or folder was moved)
  - ITEM_COPY (File or folder was copied)
  - ITEM_TRASH (File or folder was marked for deletion)
- As you might notice, each event type listed above applies to Files AND Folders.  If you are strictly interested in files, then the event `source` field has a `type` property that indicates whether the item is a `file` or `folder`.

Hope that gets you pointed in the right direction!